# Spring is not stopping when guard exits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spring-gem

I am using guard-rspec with spring in my rails app. When I start guard and run tests, spring starts up fine. But when I exit from guard (by exit command in the console) guard exit, but it leaves spring running:

```
[1] guard(main)> exit

13:38:55 - INFO - Bye bye...
```

My guard file:

```
guard 'rspec', :spring => true do
   watch(%r{^(.*)\.(rb|haml|erb|coffee)$}) { 'spec' }
end
```

Any help would be appreciated..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guard::Rspec doesn't come with some special spring handling and the latest version 4.0 even removes the `spring` option in favor of the more common and thus flexible `cmd` option. But since a `Guardfile` is normal Ruby code, you can use `at_exit` to stop spring if you like:

```
at_exit { `spring stop` }

guard 'rspec', cmd: 'spring rspec' do
    watch(%r{^(.*)\.(rb|haml|erb|coffee)$}) { 'spec' }
end
```

Comment: This solution crashes (and doesn't stop `spring`) with the latest `guard` (2.14.1) and `spring` (2.0.2).

Comment: [guard-spring](https://github.com/mknapik/guard-spring) seems to do the trick, though!